# how to access jsp files inside sub-folders

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I had some jsp files inside `target/myproject/folder1/folder2/something.jsp` ( Iam using POM )

FYI, when I run my Tomcat Server, `http://localhost:8080` , it shows my project homepage

Then, why cannot i access above jsp as: `http://localhost:8080/folder1/folder2/something.jsp` ??

Its showing me 404!

Am I doing something wrong?

please suggest me!

**EDIT:**
I knew this seems dumb question, but please suggest me! some people keeping '-1' for my question, I dont understand reason for that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your jsp folder (and files) into the web-app directory.

Comment: BUT I dont want them inside /WEB-INF

Comment: Oh my bad. I wanted to say WEB-APP (or the equivalent according to your ide) directory. The WEB-INF directory is for pages you don't want to give access to public.